RefreshEndPoint bean not available after upgrading the MS to Springboot 3.2
After upgrading the microservice to Springboot 3.2, the application is failing with below error.Same works fine with Springboot 2.5.14
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'refreshEndpoint': No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Description:
required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint' in your configuration.
Application.properties file also contains below properties
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,refresh
management.endpoint.refresh.enabled=true
The @RefreshEndPoint bean is configured in RefreshEndpointAutoConfiguration.class which is part of spring-cloud-context.
Tried to see if there is any difference there for spring-cloud-context 3.1.8. Also tried to define similar configuration manually but that didn't work.
